# Mejorar rendimiento al cargar imagenes con reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-2015

Estoy empezando con react, y como ejercicio quiero hacer un cargador de imágenes drag & drop utilizando componentes.

El problema es que al cargar una imagen el consumo de memoria RAM del navegador se eleva, pero al arrastrar nuevamente imágenes al componente, el consumo de memoria se vuelve a elevar a pesar de que las imágenes anteriormente cargadas ya se eliminaron.

```js
class ImagesLoader extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {images: []}
    this.AddImages = this.AddImages.bind(this)
    this.handleUpdateImages = this.handleUpdateImages.bind(this)
  }

  AddImages(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let images= []
    let files = e.dataTransfer.files
    for(let i = 0; i < files.length;i++){
      let file = files[i]
      if(file.type.split('/')[0] === "image"){
        let name = file.name.substring(0,file.name.lastIndexOf("."))
        let newImage = {
          title: name,
          file: file,
          category: 1
        }
        images.push(newImage)
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      images: images
    })
  }

  handleUpdateImages(upImages){
    this.setState({images: upImages})
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div
        className="ImagesLoader">
        <Droparea onDropFiles={this.AddImages}/>
        <Previews
          images={this.state.images}
          onUpdateImages={this.handleUpdateImages}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Droparea extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleDragOver = this.handleDragOver.bind(this)
    this.handleDragLeave = this.handleDragLeave.bind(this)
  }

  handleDragOver(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let target = e.target
    target.classList.add('over')
  }

  handleDragLeave(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let target = e.target
    target.classList.remove('over')
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div
        className="Droparea"
        onDragOver={this.handleDragOver}
        onDragLeave={this.handleDragLeave}
        onDrop={this.props.onDropFiles}>
        <span className="Droparea-text"> Drag your elements Here. </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Previews extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleChangeItem = this.handleChangeItem.bind(this)
  }

  handleChangeItem(oldItem,prop,newValue){
    let images = this.props.images
    images.map((image) => {
      if(image === oldItem){
        image[prop] = newValue
      }
    })
    this.props.onUpdateImages(images)
  }

  render(){
    let images = this.props.images
    const imageList = images.map(image =>
      <PreviewItem
            key={image.file.name}
            image={image}
            onChangeItem={this.handleChangeItem}/>
    )

    return(
      <ul className="Previews">
        {imageList}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

class PreviewItem extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleChangeTitle = this.handleChangeTitle.bind(this)
    this.handleChangeCategory = this.handleChangeCategory.bind(this)
  }

  handleChangeTitle(value){
    this.props.onChangeItem(this.props.image,'title',value)
  }

  handleChangeCategory(value){
    this.props.onChangeItem(this.props.image,'category',value)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <li className="Preview-item">
        <PreviewItemImg image={this.props.image}/>
        <PreviewItemForm
          image={this.props.image}
          onChangeTitle={this.handleChangeTitle}
          onChangeCategory={this.handleChangeCategory}
          />
      </li>
    )
  }
}

class PreviewItemImg extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {image: this.props.image, src: false}
    this.getImage().then(src => {
      this.setState({src: src.src})
    })
  }

  getImage(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      let image = this.props.image.file
      let fileReader = new FileReader()
      fileReader.onload = function(){
        let base64 = this.result
        let img = new Image()
        img.onload = function(){
          resolve(this)
        }
        img.src = base64
      }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(image)
    })
  }

  render(){
    if(!this.state.src){
      return null
    }
    return(
      <div className="Preview-item-img">
        <img className="Item-img" src={this.state.src}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class PreviewItemForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    let title = (this.props.image.file.name === this.props.image.name)
             ? this.props.image.file.name
             : this.props.image.title
    this.state = {
      title: title,
      category: this.props.image.category
    }
    this.handleChangeTitle = this.handleChangeTitle.bind(this)
    this.handleChangeCategory = this.handleChangeCategory.bind(this)
  }

  handleChangeTitle(e){
    let value = e.target.value
    this.setState({title: value})
    this.props.onChangeTitle(value)
  }

  handleChangeCategory(e){
    let value = e.target.value
    this.setState({category: value})
    this.props.onChangeCategory(value)
  }


  render(){
    const categories = [
      {value: 1, name: 'Animals'},
      {value: 2, name: 'Cgi'},
      {value: 3, name: 'Landscapes'},
      {value: 4, name: 'Women'}
    ]
    return(
      <form className="Preview-item-form">
        <input type="text"
               placeholder="Insert title"
               onChange={this.handleChangeTitle}
               value={this.state.title}
        />
        <select value={this.state.category}
                onChange={this.handleChangeCategory}>
          {
            categories.map((c) =>
              <option
                key={c.value}
                value={c.value}>
                {c.name}
              </option>
            )
          }
        </select>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ImagesLoader />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.ImagesLoader {
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  width: 100%;
}
.ImagesLoader .Droparea {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #808080;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.ImagesLoader .Droparea.over {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  background-color: #ff6347;
}
.ImagesLoader .Previews {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
.ImagesLoader .Previews .Preview-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: dashed 1px #ff6347;
}
.Preview-item-img {
  position: relative;
}
.Preview-item-img img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

    <div id='root'>

    </div>
```

Que creen que sea la causa del problema referente a la memoria RAM?

**NOTA:**

Si observan alguna mala práctica en mi código por favor háganmelo saber,

Comment: No veo nada extraño en tu código. Haces los bind fuers del render, cosa que es correcta. Ya te digo, que es normal que ciertad APIs consuman un poco más de RAM/CPU. ¿De cuánto estás hablando? Por otro lado, esto lo pueded ver con más detalle en las herramientas de desarrollador del.navegador. Allí puedes ver en qué punto exacto se eleva el consumo.

Answer (score 0):

No veo ningun tipo de perdida de memoria (`memory leak`) he utilizado la herramienta en chrome de rendimiento y el comportamiento es normal, este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver he probado con diferentes imágenes y sin conseguir resultado de perdida de memoria los picos se elevan cuando hago el drop pero la memoria vuelve a estabilizarse lo cual utilizas alrededor de `52MB - 57MB`

Y en el código no veo indicios de `memory leak` tampoco. Por favor comprueba que tus extensiones no estén afectando el rendimiento en tu pagina (chrome , firefox). Lo mejor sería que pruebes tu código en modo incognito si a temas de memoria es el caso.